# Use Eleventy 11ty Nested Data to Generate Pages

Tags: collections, pagination, eleventy

I have a nested local data object (`locale.json`). And would like to use it to generate child folders and pages.

**Folder structure**

```
src/
  locale/   
    locale.json
```

**locale.json**

```
{
  "currency": "USD",
  "language": "en-US",
  "groups": [
    {
      "name": "Group A",
      "types": [
        {
          "name": "Type 1",
          "members": [
            {
              "id": "ABCD1234567890"
            },
            {
              "id": "EFGH0987654321"
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

I would like to generate 1 page per member in their group for each locale.

Example: `/en-US/group-a/ABCD1234567890.html`

```
dist/
  en-US/
    group-a/
      ABCD1234567890.html
```

But, I haven't found a way to use 11ty pagination or collections to make it happen.

I'm new to 11ty data and would appreciate your help.

Thanks!